# Why Eigenvector space is not linear?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

It must be simple but I do not see it.  Consider a set X, whose element are set of eigenvectors of Hermitian positive definite matrices. Why X is not linear? Any comments please?

Comment: Hmm, is $0\in X$?

Comment: Hmm, are you restricting to matrices of a fixed size, so adding eigenvectors makes sense?

Comment: Your question is vague. What is $X$, which matrices, etc, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you have eignnvectors of different eigenvalues?  If $T(x) = \lambda x$ and $T(y) = \mu y$, then $T(x+y) = \lambda x + \mu y$, which is not  a scalar multiple of $x + y$, unless $\lambda = \mu$.

Comment: Thank you, I knew something very simple I was missing.